# How to use arrows to change page in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

With jquery I need to do something like this...

A user will follow a link to a users photo gallery on my social network site.  A photo will load on the page and comments related to that photo with paging will be under the photo.  Basicly this photo and comments will be a seperate page that is loaded in with AJAX, then when a user presses the left or right arrow key, I would like to load a different photo/comments page into the page.

So far it sounds pretty simple I think but I would like to append something to the URL when a new page is loaded.  Lets say a page will be like this in the URL photos.php?user_id=2342323&photo_id=4234124 when they use arrow to load next image it should change to add something like this on #3523543 then when a user copy/paste that URL it would load the correct photo in the browser.

Any ideas how to do this in jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple jQuery [keyup](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/keyup#fn) listener will be more than sufficient to fill that role.

Basically, you take advantage of a browser quirk that allows you to rewrite the URL with

```
window.location = 'something';
```

without reloading the page. Then you implement a client-side listener to create the resultant permalink.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the url (window.location) without causing a reload. You could provide the url to the new photo somewhere in your page though.

Comment: I understand what you are saying however Facebook does it the way I mention, when it loads a new image into the page, it doesnt reload the page however it adds # followed by numbers and updates that with a new number each time a photo is loaded in.  I think myspace does it now too

Comment: If you `window.location` to the current URL plus `#` (you can also put stuff after the #, which is the key here), the browser will not refresh, no matter what the pragma/cache settings are.

Answer (score -1):

Might be best to have a "Share This" link (a la Amazon, etc) that has the correct URL.

Answer (score -1):

Facebook does this, I think.  Perhaps you could take a look at the source of a Facebook album to see how it's done, and translate that concept to jQuery?

Comment: This is exactly where the idea came from.  I have reasearched there code a lot but I was not able to figure out how they do it, they have there own JS framework it's beyond my skills